# Does Spring Repository work on Entity or Tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I have a REST API in Spring Boot which has 2 Entities namely User and Post. I also repositories for both of them which extend JPARepository. My Post table has a column which refers User_id from the Users table. Now I wanted to ask that the method findPostbyUserid in Post repository works because my post table has the user_id column or because each Post Entity has a user object in it ? Thanks

Posts.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(
        name="Posts", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"title"})}
)
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "Content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

User.java

```
package com.springboot.blog.springbootblog.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Set;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Post> posts;
}
```

PostRepository.java

```
package com.springboot.blog.springbootblog.Repository;

import com.springboot.blog.springbootblog.Entity.Post;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findByUserId(long userId);
}
```

SQL Query and Output for table Posts

```
select * from posts;
 id |        content        |        description        |       title        | user_id 
----+-----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------
  1 | My First Blog Content | My First Blog Description | My First Blog Post |       1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the method findPostbyUserid in Post repository works because my post table has the user_id column or because each Post Entity has a user object in it ?

Either answer are true. Spring Boot Data works with entities. And each entity class is a representation of a database table. The repository method findByUserId works because:

1. entity class is correctly implemented and
2. database table is correctly defined and
3. it contains the correct values (user_id).

Comment: So that means that I can implement findByUsername as well because Post entity has User object but table does not have the username field in it ?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Mar-Z, the referencing of the user works precisely because both conditions are met.

- The underlying database tables `users` and `posts` need some kind of association, in your case the `user_id` foreign key in the `posts` table, in order to be able to filter for a particular user in the query. This is the prerequisite to write SQL queries.
- So that you do not have to write the SQL queries yourself, use Spring Data JPA and abstract the specific database access. Spring Data JPA works with Jakarta entities and maps them to SQL tables. In order to generate the automated SQL query that is behind `findByUserId()`, Spring Data JPA must also know about the association. The association is established at the level of Spring Data JPA via `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` and the corresponding classes properties.

For more information see:

- [Spring Data JPA Repository - Defining Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)
- [Jakarta Persistence API - Bidirectional ManyToOne / OneToMany Relationships](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#bidirectional-manytoone-onetomany-relationships)